# Node urls indexed by Google

Tags: nodes

I am pretty new to Drupal, can someone tell me why ive got lots of node urls in my index on Google, is this because i havent given the post on my site a friendly url ?

Is there a way to fix this or do i have to edit every post with a node url ?

Is there a way to stop this happening in future

JC

Comment: You'll want to add a canonical URL in your page metadata. There are a couple of module based solutions out there like metatags.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce the content indexed by search engines use your robots.txt file to instruct them to ignore certain paths or sets of paths.

Many Drupal projects use Path, Pathauto and one of redirect modules to automatically assign aliases to links. Usually, the path pattern is set to automatically replace `node/[nid]` with something like `content/[title]`. Globalredirect or Redirect modules permanently automatically redirect from the default Drupal query to the alias, so there is nothing else you have to do (no need to edit Robots.txt unless you want to exclude some of them).

Path aliases can be generated automatically for existing content so it will work for your case and also in the future.

Comment: So if i have a page that has a node url that i want to make into a proper friendly url, what is the best thing to do ? do i have to indiidually edit them or use the modules you have mentioned ?

Comment: You don't have to edit individually. In Pathauto configuration there is the `Bulk generate` option where you can choose to assign new aliases to old content, taxonomy or users. Just make sure you configure Patterns and Settings before generating them in bulk to avoid needless repetition.